# tableView doesn't show the sections after array gets filtered

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, predicate

I want to filter an array with predicate and show it in tableView, every row of the array should be displayed in one section, but nothing is shown when I run my app.
When I try it with the unfiltered array it works. I don't know what to do because the two arrays have the same structure, the only difference is that the unfiltered array contains 17 objects and the filtered one 11.
Here's my code:

In viewDidLoad:

```
//itemsArray gets filled like this:
NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:abfahrt,@"Abfahrt",ankunft,@"Ankunft",nil];
[items addObject:dict];

//Date converted to string
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:gDate];

//filtered with stringDate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Abfahrt < %@", stringDate];
filteredArray = [itemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return filteredArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ErgebnisCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *abfahrtLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *ankunftLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    abfahrtLabel.text = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Abfahrt"];
    ankunftLabel.text = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Ankunft"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns what value? `[yourTableView reloadData]` when you get you `filteredArray`?

Comment: it returns the value 11

Comment: Have you compared/confirmed the structure of both arrays (via `NSLog(@"%@",itemsArray); NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray);`)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your filteredArray is empty, meaning your predicate is excluding everything from your list. 
Put a breakpoint on the filteredArray line to see what's in there.

Alternately, put a breakpoint inside of numberOfSectionsInTableView, and see what filteredArray.count is. If it's zero, then tweak your predicate until some of your entries can make it through.

You may also find the methods listed under the "identifying and comparing strings" section of the NSStringClassReference to be helpful in forming the predicate you want. Especially any of the "compare" methods.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: no it isn't empty I already tried this. There are 11 objects in it